# How to use Xamarin in existing iOS or Android Project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an iOS project written in Swift.

**I want to launch Xamarin.Forms Views inside iOS Native Project.
How to do two way communication from iOS Native Project to Xamarin.Forms view?**

is there any way to achieve this task?

Ex. I can achieve this task using Flutter Module.

```
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps
https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-flutter-to-existing-android-ios-app-ae8c4fb1582e
```

How to achieve above using Xamarin?

Comment: I don't think you can use forms project in the native project

Comment: any reasons, Why I can not use?
in Flutter , I can use flutter module in native Language Project.

Comment: it seems gradle supports the flutter reference.

Comment: I found the solution.Embeddinator-4000 that creates native libraries of .NET libraries. https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe can di that with the Embeddinator-4000 that creates native libraries of .NET libraries. https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000

Comment: How to use Xamarin.Forms Views in Native without making a Xamarine.Native Project.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [Xamarin Forms Native Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms)

Comment: This Link Gives information about "Xamarin.Forms in Xamarin Native Projects".
i.e How to use Xamarin.forms in Xamarin Native Project?                                                           But My Query is How to use Xamarin.Forms inside Xcode iOS project written in Swift?